# Is there a Wald test to compare the means of two indepent Poisson distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution, wald-test

I found a problem, which says

> Let $X_1,...,X_{n_1}\sim Poisson(\lambda_1), Y_1,...,Y_{n_2}\sim Poisson(\lambda_2), i.i.d$  and independent of each other.
>   $H_0:\lambda_1=\lambda_2, \ H_1: not \ H_0$.
>
> Derive the Wald's test of size $\alpha$ for testing the hypothesis, when $n_1,n_2$ are large."

I've only learned about Wald's test for random samples from 1 distribution, but I don't know how to do it when comparing 2 distributions.

And I also couldn't understand what 'large' means, because even if $n_1,n_2$ both go to infinity, the speed can be different and there was no information about that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Likelihood-based hypothesis testing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155392/likelihood-based-hypothesis-testing)

Comment: Some similar/relevant posts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9561/checking-if-two-poisson-samples-have-the-same-mean, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199008/what-is-a-statistical-significance-test-for-two-poisson-distributions, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155307/significance-of-difference-between-two-counts, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155392/likelihood-based-hypothesis-testing/155420#155420

Answer (score -1):

Since to compare means of two iid distributions, you can compute the differences between respective random variables in both samples and generate new hypotheses as,

$H_0$: $\delta\ = 0\ $
and the alternate, $H_1$: $\delta\ \ne 0\ $.

And then you would get one distribution and then you can apply the wald's test on that distribution as,

computing $estimated \ \delta\\ $ using MLE and computing the standard normal RV,

$W\ = \frac{est.\ \delta -\delta_0}{est.\ se(\ est. \ \delta\ )}\ $

And finally compare it with the given $\alpha$ value for the test.

Comment: That applies to paired data.  This is instead a two-sample problem where the order of observations within sample is irrelevant.